# SQL, WHERE id=5, but i want a certain record to show up first.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

not sure how to do this but say i have a table with a bunch of items owned by userID 5, I want to make it so that if i search for a specific item from that user, all of his items will show up, but the item searched for will appear first and the rest of the items will follow. For example:

```
Items table
-----------
itemID       userID    itemName
1              5       Coffee Mug
2              5       iPhone
3              5       LCD Monitor
4              5       Macbook pro
5              5       Shell
```

So say i do a search for an iPhone, i want my results to return all of userID's items (WHERE userID=5), but... I want the iPhone item to be at the top of the list! Thanks all for your help!

damien

Comment: Are you searching for a user, or an item? Or is it a sort only? The ORDER BY from Aaron will make the search item first, but if you search for "iphone" and userid = 5 you'll only get one row.

Comment: I'm actually would like to search by itemID. So i pass a string itemID=2 i would like to see itemID 2 first then the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY      
   case when Items.itemID = 2 then 0 else 1 end ASC      
   ,Items.itemName ASC
```

Comment: I like this solution as it shows how to sort the remaining items, as well, if needed.  Seems like that would usually be the case.

Comment: @Damien: `CASE` is very powerful and flexible, have a look yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx and http://www.extremeexperts.com/sql/articles/CASEinORDER.aspx and http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-order-by

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** now we are no longer searching for 'iPhone' we are indicating first item by @ItemID:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN itemID = @ItemID THEN 'a' ELSE 'z' END 
  --, secondary ordering
```

Comment: I'm actually would like to search by itemID. So i pass a string itemID=2 i would like to see itemID 2 first then the rest.

Comment: Updated answer to use @ItemID (assuming that its datatype matches the itemID column - which really shouldn't be a string).

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional column for the `SELECT` with a case statement that is 0 when your condition is satisfied and 1 otherwise, and then `ORDER BY` that.

Comment: You don't need to actually materialize a column for that.